# Can I query event logs for substrings?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

Using web.js, I can query the event logs of a contract using the "web3.eth.filter" method.  The documentation states that this method accepts an object with a "topics" property, which is says are "An array of values which must each appear in the log entries".

My question, can I match a substring of a topic?  For example, say I have an event like this:

```
event AddedEntity (
    string indexed _title
    string indexed _contents,
    uint256 indexed _id
);
```

and I fire that event in the smart contract like so:

```
AddedEntity("Week 34", "Interesting Data", 142);
```

Can I search the contract's event logs for the keyword "Interesting" and expect a match?  Or will I only find a match if I search for "Interesting Data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For indexed arguments, only the hash of the value is used, so no it is not possible to search for a substring, only exact values will match.